# Function pointer in argument in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have to do an exercise where I have a certain numbers of functions and every function do a different thing like sort all the negative numbers from the array.

Moreover I have to create a function `display` with 3 argument pointers to an array, size of it and a name of a function which receives `int` and that the issue is `int` (Function pointer). I try to do this but this don't work and I don't know what to do in order to do correctly this exercise with a function pointer, because I don't understand that.

This is my code

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand (time (NULL));
    int arr[MAX_SIZE], second_arr[MAX_SIZE], i;

    random_arr (arr);

    display (arr, 20, negative_number (arr, second_arr));

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void random_arr (int *my_arr)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        *(my_arr + i) = i - 10;
    }
}

int negative_number (int *arr, int *sort_arr)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            sort_arr[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return sort_arr;
}

void diplay (int *arr, int size, int (*a_function) (int, int))
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf ("%d\n", a_function);
    }
}
```

Comment: a_function in the display() function needs to have two parameters when called, and being a function pointer must be called using the * notation, to begin with.

Comment: also, when calling the display() function you just need to pass the function pointer, without arguments. I think you need a deeper understanding of function pointers syntax before trying to resolve such exercise

Comment: "a function pointer must be called using the * notation, to begin with" - no, it needn't.

Comment: @ad3angel1s: To expand on Paul's point, the prefix of a function call (before the `(`) is *always* an expression of pointer-to-function type. In the common case where it's the name of a function, that name is implicitly converted to a pointer. (That's in the abstract semantics; the generated code needn't work that way.)

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking. So you have this function `display`, which takes a function pointer. What are the inputs to the function and what are the outputs? At present (among many other problems) you aren't actually passing a function pointer, you are calling the function and passing its return value to `display`. Also you say it should take an int and return an int, but it takes 2 pointers and returns a pointer (despite your function being declared as returning int).

Comment: "this don't work" is a very poor problem description for Stack Overflow. You should tell how exactly it doesn't work. Doesn't compile, with what error, from what line? Crashes, in what line (use debugger)? Produces wrong output, what and what did you expect? Also, to make life easier for you, turn on compiler warnings and fix them as you get them (how exactly to do this depends on your compiler)..

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, right not needed to have the * in function pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be different from your intentions because your intentions is not clear.
but I think this would  be  helpful

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 20

void random_arr (int size, int *my_arr);
int negative_number (int size, int *arr, int *sort_arr);
void display (int *arr, int size, int (*filter_function) (int in_size, int *in_array, int *out_array));

int main (void){
    int arr[MAX_SIZE], second_arr[MAX_SIZE], i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    random_arr(MAX_SIZE, arr);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    puts("");
    display (arr, MAX_SIZE, negative_number);

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void random_arr (int size, int *my_arr){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        my_arr[i] = rand()%MAX_SIZE - MAX_SIZE/2;
    }
}

int negative_number (int size, int *arr, int *sort_arr){
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            sort_arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return j;//new array size
}

void display (int *arr, int size, int (*filter)(int in_size, int *in_array, int *out_array)){
    int i = 0;
    int *out = malloc(size * sizeof(*out));
    int out_size = filter(size, arr, out);

    for (i = 0; i < out_size; i++) {
        printf ("%d\n", out[i]);
    }
    free(out);
}
```